# Should I include a description of edits in the body of an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

Personally, I'm a big fan of this, especially when no answer has been accepted.

There's nothing more annoying than responding to an answer only to find that your questions or clarifications are no longer valid. Having explicit "EDIT: I changed ..." at the end of the body serves to be an instant reminder that something has been changed or fixed. The more substantial the change is, the more useful they are, as they can give context to comments that no longer apply, e.g. "Why did you do XXX instead of YYY" when the answer does YYY.

On the downside, this information is already available by looking at the edit history, and it clutters what may be an otherwise succinct answer.

What's the proper thing to do here?

Answer (score 16):

When applying an edit to your post, please don't mention you edited it. That is irrelevant to the post itself.

Flag the comment for being obsolete instead, and/or @notify the poster of the comment that you addressed their concern in your post. They can check the revision history of the post to see what you changed.

**Edit:** obligatory meta ninja-edit.

Comment: I could agree that this is a strong argument for removing the "EDIT:" mentions after an answer is accepted; at some point a question transitions from being a discussion of the problem and the solutions to being a long-term archive where the edits are irrelevant, but when a question is actively being discussed, it seems reasonable (though not required) to include information on the nature of edits.